# Start frontend Deferred task from backend on App Engine/Java

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to start a Deferred frontend task from a Deferred backend on App Engine/Java.  Deferred Tasks are started on the backend using a specific host with code like:

```
queue.add(withPayload(new MyDeferredTask()).header("Host",
    BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("backend1", 1));
```

And this works well.  If a Deferred task is started from this backend then the task also runs on the backend.  Is there a specific host to be used, or another means of explicitly starting a Deferred task on the frontend?

**Update**

I missed out a bit of important info in the original question:  I'm talking about Deferred Tasks, where a payload is passed in.  Starting a Deferred task from a backend starts the new Deferred task in the same backend. What I want to know is if its possible to explicitly start a Deferred task in the frontend, when its started from a backend.  The original question above has been modified to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my old question, specifically for deferred tasks - if you have a task running on a backend and want to start a task on the frontend, you should explicitly specify the host of the frontend instance i.e. myapp.appspot.com. If you don't specify a host then the task will run on the same instance as the starting code.

To explcitly start on the frontend, regardless of the instance the caller is running on, do something like:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("my-queue");
TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(new MyDeferredTask());
taskOptions.header("Host", "myappid.appspot.com");
queue.add(taskOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `URL` of your front-end "servlet you want to run" with the `URL-fetch service` or add a task to one queue with the servlet's url.

Front-ends just handle all the HTTP calls to your application and send it to the servlet configured in the web.xml file

Comment: Thanks. However, I missed a crucial bit of information - my issue is to do with starting Deferred tasks from a backend, not a standard task which is referred to by URL.  I've updated the original question.